# how to stop the element at footer line while moving it up and down with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I added an element which moves up and down with scroll, but the problem is its collapsing with footer. Below is the sample code which I am using for it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var top = $('#comment').offset().top - parseFloat($('#comment').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= top) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      $('#comment').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      $('#comment').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

Sample HTML code

```
<div id="commentWrapper">
  <div id="comment">
    <form>
      <!-- take their response -->
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by giving `bottom:somevalue` and its working fine now